# Minimum version for Wordpress Backbone

Tags: wp-admin, backbone

How do I find the minimum Wordpress version required if I want to use Backbone on a plugin? I'm building a Wordpress plugin, and I can't find documentation online that records when Wordpress first used Backbone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It was introduced in 3.5](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21664) for the media library, but it's been periodically updated since then. Honestly, it's been around long enough that you're almost certainly using something else that has a more recent requirement.